# Run single-threaded in parallel in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, single-threaded

I have a simulation that can run only one at a time and takes 50-100 ms (CPU intensive).
It is available behind an HTTP API.
The requirement is to execute around 1000 HTTP requests per second (or around 100 instances in parallel).

I tried Azure Functions hoping they will increase the number instances as the number of requests grows, but I only got 2 running (using both Consumption and App Service plan).

Is there some solution for this scenario?

Comment: That number seems off. HTTP scales out pretty aggressively (or it should). Can you provide any more details of the app config and how you tracked active instance count?